# How to convert svg to ipe?

Tags: python, svg

I am currently using IPE to draw diagrams for LaTeX. I have found online a svgtoipe converter using python3 : https://github.com/otfried/ipe-tools/blob/master/svgtoipe/svgtoipe.py
But I do not understand at all how to use it with my svg file.
So I am asking for help to use this program, it would be much appreciated.

**Edit : The command that worked was `py path\svgtoipe.py path\my-file-name.svg`**

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: I have python 3.7.4 using Pyzo, I can run the script but I get an error : "usage: [-h] [-c] svg-file.svg [ipe-file.ipe]: error: the following arguments are required: svg-file.svg"
So yes, I do not know how to pass the svg file to the script. Thanks for asking.

Comment: I added some pictures. I am not using any command because I do not know what to do. I am math and physics student so I only use python (with pyzo) for algorithms and I am not so familiar with other aspects.

Comment: get a terminal prompt, type <path to svg>/svg-file.svg <file to convert> (that should work on unix and mac) on Windows you'd likely need to do py <path to svg>/svg-file.svg <file to convert> or even py3 depending on how python is installed.

Comment: Or just google how to run a python program from the command line on whatever operating system you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am using Windows, I opened cmd, but I don't suceed. Well the path is : 'C:\Users\Axel\Desktop\' and my file name is 'dessin.svg', could you please help me a bit further please? I am going to edit my post so you can see my prompt.

Comment: https://www.cs.bu.edu/courses/cs108/guides/runpython.html

Comment: Please do not post images of code.

Comment: I have finally suceeded to run a script using the terminal, thanks for that. But I still don't get how to pass my file...

Comment: Well it worked, thank you, it generated a document.